# Custom Comparator.comparing only by field in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, compare, comparator, compareto

I want to implement a comparator in Java 8 to compare only by fields, using Comparator.comparing(....).

The functionality that I want to achieve is below:

```
List<DocumentLink> documentList = documentLinkService.getDocumentList(baseInstance);
        //call of custom comparator for DigitalFileCategory due to compare only by Name
        documentList = documentList.stream()
                .filter(doc -> category.comp(doc.getDigitalFileCategory()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So I need a boolean returned value.
Comp method in DigitalFileCategory:

```
public boolean comp(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj) ||
            (obj != null &&
                    getName() != null &&
                    getName().equals(((DigitalFileCategory) obj).getName()));
}
```

Any ideas, how can I do that?
When I tried to implement a Comparator.comparing asked me to make getName static.

DigitalFileCategory.class

```
public class DigitalFileCategory extends _Base {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "iddigitalfilecategory", nullable = false)
    private Integer iddigitalfilecategory;

    @Column(name = "Name", length = 64)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Priority")
    private Integer priority;
    //    getter && setter
}
```

Comment: Provide us the basic information about `DocumentLink` and `DigitalFileFactory` classes, please.

Comment: Why do you need a Comparator?

Comment: `Comparator` is for ordering, not for equality.

Comment: Comparator is for comparing: equals, greater or less, but you want check for equality.

Comment: I need the comparator for equality due to filter distinct by Name

Comment: We're telling you you don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to create you comparator to take the `name` property out of `DigitalFileCategory`.

```
Comparator<DigitalFileCategory> categoryNameComparator =
    Comparator.comparing((DigitalFileCategory arg) -> arg.getName());
```

and then you need to follow its contract while using it (`0` being returned for equal entities according to this comparator):

```
documentList = documentList.stream()
              .filter(doc -> 0 == categoryNameComparator.compare(category, doc.getDigitalFileCategory()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However why such a complex solution, cannot you simply do simple equality check (assuming that `category` & `doc.getDigitalFileCategory()` never return `null`)?

```
documentList = documentList.stream()
              .filter(doc -> Objects.equals(category.getName(), doc.getDigitalFileCategory().getName()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that I need to compare only by Name.

Comment: @pkont Got it. Amended the `Object.equals` proposal. Assuming that `doc.getDFC()` and `category` are never null.